# Python Loop is printing result Twice from MYSQL database

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, printing, abstract-syntax-tree

## Solved!

Turns out I had called my script `json.py` and was importing `json` so the python script was calling itself, therefore, running twice.

## Problem

Here is my code below, It access a database and returns data within:

```
import mysql.connector
import ast
import json

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database="db"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT cast FROM credits LIMIT 2")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
  dictionary = None
  dictionary = ast.literal_eval(str(x))
  dictionary = ast.literal_eval(dictionary[0])
  for a in dictionary:
    print(a["character"])
    #Need to insert the data into a JSON object here
  print("\n")
```

It then gives me this output In cmd:

```
Woody (voice)
Buzz Lightyear (voice)
Mr. Potato Head (voice)
Slinky Dog (voice)
Rex (voice)

Alan Parrish
Samuel Alan Parrish / Van Pelt
Judy Sheperd
Peter Shepherd

Woody (voice)
Buzz Lightyear (voice)
Mr. Potato Head (voice)
Slinky Dog (voice)
Rex (voice)

Alan Parrish
Samuel Alan Parrish / Van Pelt
Judy Sheperd
Peter Shepherd
```

The data is being printed out twice? I'm new to python and from research, It might be with indentation am I missing something?

## Updates

The issue is not due to duplicate records in data (TESTED)

Comment: You're doing a query with limit 2 - so it looks like the first two entries in your db are identical.

Comment: @Daniel I tested this by ordering the request and checking the data, I can confirm that it's still repeating with no duplicate records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

I called my script `json.py` and then import `json` so I think the script is calling itself so, therefore, running twice.

I renamed my script and the issue is fixed!